# Usage of in a such a way

Tags: conjunctions

I wonder if the usage of '' in such a way '' correct in sentence below.

'' He was founded in such a way that his arm has been broken by his freind ''.

I mean ; Does this sentence above maean ''he was founded with arm which was broken by his friend''. If it is wrong , What should i use to give this meaning ?

Comment: "Founded" is the past participle of "to found", which means "to establish", as in "he founded an organization to support cancer research." I think you intend to use the past participle of "to find", which is "*found*".

Answer (score 0):

First, you most likely mean *found* here, not *founded*. (*Founded* would imply that he was *made* in such a way that . . .)

But the sentence still doesn't really make sense.

Consider this revision for clarity:

> The search was conducted in such a way that his arm had been broken by his friend.

Despite the still-awkward construction at the end, *in such a way* is modifying the first part of the sentence. Or, in other words:

> The method of the search caused his friend to break his arm.

I don't think this is your intended meaning. (Although if it actually is, the revised version would be more natural.)

---

It's likely that you want to rephrase your sentence to something like this:

> When he was found, **his arm was arranged** in such a way that it indicated it had been broken by his friend.

Of course, it's still not clear how this conclusion could be drawn without further context, but the syntax of the sentence now makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

I would say it like this:

He was found with his arm broken. His arm had been broken by his friend.

Or

When he was found, they learned / found out that his arm had been broken by his friend.